# Is DML not allowed in a Visualforce getter?

Tags: apex, visualforce, dml, limitexception

## Summary

I am trying to simplify some code for a page that makes a callout, then logs the request and response. I stumbled across a scenario in which the log record appears to create successfully, but then no longer exists outside the transaction boundary.

**Why does the `insert` succeed but the record ceases to exist immediately outside the transaction?**

---

## MVR

#### Page

```
<apex:page controller="Demo">
    <apex:pageMessages rendered="{!someProperty}" />
</apex:page>
```

#### Controller

```
public class Demo
{
    public Boolean someProperty
    {
        get
        {
            HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
            request.setEndpoint('https://someUri');
            request.setMethod('GET');
            new Http().send(request);

            Integration_Log__c log = new Integration_Log__c();
            insert log;

            system.debug(log.Id);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

#### Error

If I take the above `log.Id` and navigate to the record, I get:

> **Data Not Available**
>   The data you were trying to access could not be found. It may be due to another user deleting the data or a system error. If you know the data is not deleted but cannot access it, please look at our [support](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/htdoor?body=%2Ftrain%2FonlineSupport.jsp&loc=support&language=en_US&release=206.7.2&instance=CS23&showSplash=true) page.

I can't see the record via query either.

---

## Further Investigation

I changed the getter pattern to use an explicitly defined method and got a different error.

**Controller**

```
public Boolean getSomeProperty()
{
    insert new Integration_Log__c();
    return false;
}
```

**Error**

> **DML currently not allowed**
>   An unexpected error has occurred. Your development organization has been notified.

And the debug log shows:

> System.LimitException: DML currently not allowed

**Additional Questions**

**Is DML not allowed in a `Visualforce` getter?** I can't find any official reference that is the case. In fact, the only reference I can find is [an eight year old blog post by Wes Nolte](https://th3silverlining.com/2009/11/23/dml-currently-not-allowed/). It's certainly allowed in getters in general. For example placing the above getter logic into `Execute Anonymous` will cause the record to insert successfully.

Comment: I [moved our discussion to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53019/discussion-on-question-by-adrian-larson-getter-callout-dml-data-not-availa) to reduce clutter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here ya go. According to [Considerations for Creating Custom Controllers and Controller Extensions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_considerations.htm?search_text=dml)

> - You can't use data manipulation language (DML) operations in a
>     “getxxx” method in a controller. For example, if your controller had a
>     getName method, you could not use insert or update in the method to
>     create an object

FYI: `@future` methods are never executed in this scenario either.

---

Not sure if it meets your requirements or not but you might consider using the page `action` as a potential workaround.

#### Page

```
<apex:page controller="Demo" action="{!doCallout}">
    <apex:pageMessages rendered="{!someProperty}" />
</apex:page>
```

#### Controller

```
public class Demo
{
    public Boolean someProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

     public void doCallout(){

            HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
            request.setEndpoint('https://someUri');
            request.setMethod('GET');
            new Http().send(request);

            Integration_Log__c log = new Integration_Log__c();
            insert log;

            system.debug(log.Id);


     }

}
```

Comment: Yeah the ubiquitous "put it in your page action" workaround. I don't care about logging on the initialization callouts quite as much. It's more of a *should* have than a *must* have. I wonder if getters can call `@future` methods...

Comment: @AdrianLarson - i just tried, future method is never executed. No log of it either

Comment: I hit this recently as well, I think I even tried queuable with similar results to using @future.

Comment: getters also do not persist Platform Cache puts